# In SharePoint Online modern site global navigation does not show links if updated in Navigation settings page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, global-navigation

I have a SharePoint Online modern site. I tried to add few links from the global navigation settings through the "Navigation Settings" page.
If I go to the site settings page the updated version of the Global navigation is displayed, but when I go to the home page of the same site still the old global navigation is displayed.

Please help me in resolving this.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait for 24 hours. If the problem still exists, please create new service request in O365 admin center.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do Microsoft has any article which mentions about this time duration to wait to reflect the changes we have done on global navigation in modern site?

Please help with such article if exists or any O365 configuration where I can see this.
This is because I have to explain to the business managers regarding this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There isn‘t any article about the duration to wait from Microsoft currently. If you still want to know about this, new service request can help you too:)